# How swift implement the default Decodable for struct?

Tags: swift, compiler-construction

```swift
struct Person: Decodable {
    let firstName: String
}
var data = """
{"firstName": "Fai"}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let parsed = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)
```

`JSONDecoder` will decode the data, which is comfirmed to `Decodable` protocol.

So I want to know how swift implement this. But I can not get any idea in the source code: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift

The `Decodable` protocol only need to implement an `init(from decoder: Decoder)` function.
If I am going to do it, I will make an extension for struct:

```
extension struct: Decodable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) {...}
}
```

But when I delete the Decodable on my example, the compiler give errors:

> Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that 'Person' conform to 'Decodable'

So this is not the swift way to implement this. How's swift way? And where's the source code?

Comment: Extension struct?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking how Swift implements the automatic synthesis of `init(from:)`, and how *you* can implement something similar too?

Comment: @Sweeper  Yes, I want to know how swift implements this, and I want to learn from it.

Comment: Default synthesis of Codable conformance It is built into the compiler: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceCodable.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what the compiler writes for you using `-print-ast`:

```
echo 'struct Person: Decodable {
    let firstName: String
}' | swiftc -print-ast -
```

This will output most of the auto-generated code (it should include all of the Codable conformances, but there are a few other kinds of auto-generated code that won't include their implementation):

```swift
internal struct Person : Decodable {
  internal let firstName: String
  private enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
    case firstName
    @_implements(Equatable, ==(_:_:)) fileprivate static func __derived_enum_equals(_ a: Person.CodingKeys, _ b: Person.CodingKeys) -> Bool {
      private var index_a: Int
      switch a {
      case .firstName:

        index_a = 0
      }
      private var index_b: Int
      switch b {
      case .firstName:

        index_b = 0
      }
      return index_a == index_b
    }
    fileprivate func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      private var discriminator: Int
      switch self {
      case .firstName:

        discriminator = 0
      }
      hasher.combine(discriminator)
    }
    private init?(stringValue: String) {
      switch stringValue {
      case "firstName":

        self = Person.CodingKeys.firstName
        default:

        return nil
      }

    }
    private init?(intValue: Int) {
      return nil
    }
    fileprivate var hashValue: Int {
      get {
        return _hashValue(for: self)
      }
    }
    fileprivate var intValue: Int? {
      get {
        return nil
      }
    }
    fileprivate var stringValue: String {
      get {
        switch self {
        case .firstName:

          return "firstName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  internal init(firstName: String)
  internal init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    @_hasInitialValue private let container: KeyedDecodingContainer<Person.CodingKeys> = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Person.CodingKeys.self)

    self.firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: Person.CodingKeys.firstName)

  }
}
```

For the full implementation details, see [DerivedConformanceCodable.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceCodable.cpp). Probably of most interest to your question is [`deriveBodyDecodable_init`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceCodable.cpp#L1294-L1531).